# Reorder one row in tibble - move it to the last row

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I rearrange the rows in tibble?

I wish to reorder rows such that: row with x = "c" goes to the bottom of the tibble, everything else remains same.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
              y = 1:8)
```

Comment: Create a new column such as `mutate(Idx=ifelse(x == "c", 99, row_number())` and then `arrange(Idx)`.  Both functions in your pipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to *dplyr::arrange()*, using base R:

```
tbl[order(tbl$x == "c"), ] # Thanks to Merijn van Tilborg
```

Output:

```r
#   x         y
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a         1
# 2 b         2
# 3 d         4
# 4 e         5
# 5 f         6
# 6 g         7
# 7 h         8
# 8 c         3
```

Answer (score 4):

```r
tbl |> dplyr::arrange(x == "c")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *forcats*, convert to factor having **c** the last, then *arrange*. This doesn't change the class of the column *x*.

```
library(forcats)

tbl %>% 
  arrange(fct_relevel(x, "c", after = Inf))
  
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
#   x         y
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a         1
# 2 b         2
# 3 d         4
# 4 e         5
# 5 f         6
# 6 g         7
# 7 h         8
# 8 c         3
```

If the order of *x* is important, it is better to keep it as factor class, below will change the class from character to factor with **c** being last:

```
tbl %>% 
  mutate(x = fct_relevel(x, "c", after = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(x)
```